# How to find the sum of all the even numbers in a nested object(recursively)?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am getting `6` as output but correct output is `10`. What am I doing wrong?

**Here is my code:**

```js
function nestedEvenSum(object) {
    let sum = 0;

    function helper(object) {
        // console.log(object); //For Debug Purpose
        let values = Object.values(object);
        if (values[0] instanceof Object) {
            return helper(values[0]);
        } else if (values[0] % 2 === 0) {
            sum += values[0];
        }
        delete object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
        if (Object.keys(object).length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        return (helper(object));
    }
    helper(object);
    return sum;
}
```

**TestCase:**

```js
var obj1 = {
    a: 2,
    b: {
        b: 2,
        bb: {
            b: 3,
            bb: {
                b: 2
            }
        }
    },
    c: {
        c: {
            c: 2
        },
        cc: 'ball',
        ccc: 5
    },
    d: 1,
    e: {
        e: {
            e: 2
        },
        ee: 'car'
    }
};

console.log(nestedEvenSum(obj1)); // 10
```

Comment: Use a loop for enumerating properties, do not use `delete`. Use `typeof`  instead of `instanceof`. Make `nestedEventSum` itself recursive, do not use a helper function.

Comment: The problem is that your `helper` function ignores further keys in an object when it determined that the first value in there is an object. It would work if you removed the `return` keywords in front of the recursive calls so that both could run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you find the first element is an Object you return rather than just call recursively. That stops it from moving to the next element in the current object so you never get to the `object.c` part and stop prematurely. This should work:

```js
function nestedEvenSum(object) {
    let sum = 0;

    function helper(object) {
        // console.log(object); //For Debug Purpose
        let values = Object.values(object);
        if (values[0] instanceof Object) {
            helper(values[0]);   // Call recursively but do not return
        } else if (values[0] % 2 === 0) {
            sum += values[0];
        }
        delete object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
        if (Object.keys(object).length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        return (helper(object));
    }
    helper(object);
    return sum;
}
```

The way you had it caused the processing of an object to stop after the first Object it found because you `return` and miss the part later that deletes and calls again for the next element in the object.

Comment: Thanks alot...now I understand that when object.b is solved then then original object returns without moving to the next elements hence not all values are explored.

Answer (score 3):

Use closure and recursively traverse the object. No need the mutate the actual object passed as parameter. This is not a good practise.

```
function sumEven(obj) {
 let sum = 0

 function traverse(obj) {
   for(k in obj) {
    if(typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
        traverse(obj[k])
    } else if(typeof(obj[k]) === 'number' && obj[k]%2 === 0) {
      sum += obj[k]
    }
   }
 }

 traverse(obj)

 return sum
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but since I am new and I don't know about closures,I didn't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```js
var obj1 = {
    a: 2,
    b: {
        b: 2,
        bb: {
            b: 3,
            bb: {
                b: 2
            }
        }
    },
    c: {
        c: {
            c: 2
        },
        cc: 'ball',
        ccc: 5
    },
    d: 1,
    e: {
        e: {
            e: 2
        },
        ee: 'car'
    }
};

function getEvens(o) {
  var evens = []
  Object.values(o).forEach(function(v){
    if (v%2 == 0) { evens.push(v) }
    if (typeof(v) === 'object') {
      evens = evens.concat(getEvens(v))
    }
  })
  return evens
}

console.log(getEvens(obj1).reduce((a,b)=>a+b))
```

Your algorithm only checks the first object encountered and recursively checks within, so you only ass the three "2" encountered this way.

Comment: Why so complicated with the `evens` array? Just sum them already. If you really wanted to build an array, I'd suggest using `flatMap`  instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `helper` function ignores further keys in an object when it determined that the first value in there is an object. It would work if you removed the `return` keywords in front of the recursive calls so that both could run (like in @AlwaysLearning's answer).

However, I'd suggest to simplifiy the whole thing. Use a loop for enumerating properties, do not use `delete` that destroys the argument object. Use `typeof` instead of `instanceof`. And there's no need for the `helper` function, you can make `nestedEventSum` itself recursive. Here's a cleaned-up solution with an explicit recursion base case:

```
function nestedEvenSum(o) {
    if (typeof o == "number") {
        if (o % 2 == 0)
            return o;
        else
            return 0;
    } else if (typeof o == "object") {
        let sum = 0;
        for (const p in o)
            sum += nestedEvenSum(p[o]);
        return sum;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Can only handle objects or numbers");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will account these suggestions in future.

Answer (score 0):

Without helper function

```
function nestedEvenSum (obj, sum=0) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
            sum += nestedEvenSum(obj[key]);
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'number' && obj[key] % 2 === 0){
            sum += obj[key];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

As this was recently brought back up, here's another approach:

```js
const nestedEvenSum = (xs) =>
  xs .constructor == String
    ? 0 // or: parseInt (xs, 10) || 0 // or however you want to handle strings
  : xs .constructor == Number
    ? xs % 2 == 0 ? xs : 0
  : xs .constructor === Array
    ? xs .map (nestedEvenSum) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  : xs .constructor == Object
    ? nestedEvenSum (Object .values (xs))
  : 0 // default, for unknown types

const obj1 = {a: 2, b: {b: 2, bb: {b: 3, bb: {b: 2}}}, c: {c: {c: 2}, cc: 'ball', ccc: 5}, d: 1, e: {e: {e: 2}, ee: 'car'}}

console .log (nestedEvenSum (obj1))
```

Our recursive function calculates the sum of the nested even elements by returning even numbers, returning `0` for any strings, recurring on an object's values,  recurring and summing on an array, and returning `0` for any other values.

The advantage of this is that we can easily extend to other types.  We might well want to handle `null` or `undefined` values, and we can do that by starting the chain of conditions with

```js
  xs == null
    ? 0
```

and perhaps we want to handle `Set`s or `Map`s or even `Function`s.  Those become almost trivial to add:

```js
  : xs .constructor === Set
    ? nestedEvenSum ([...xs])
  : xs .constructor === Map
    ? nestedEvenSum ([...xs .values()])
  : xs .constructor === Function
    ? nestedEvenSum (xs ()) // or just 0?
```

And we could just as easily handle custom types as needed.  But we don't have to deal with any of these, handling only those types we choose.